# Могли б помочь понять почему big query не восприимчив к изменению даты в условии where

Tags: sql, запрос, bigquery

Вот запрос , который обрабатывает  34 гигабайта
Когда я пробую поменять в условии where 365 дней на 3 - на размер запроса это не влияет , хотя ему при этом нужно обработать в 20-30 раз меньше строк.
Почему так ?

```
SELECT
Project,
Player,
DATE(DATE_SUB(created_at, INTERVAL 5 hour)) AS Date,
COUNT(PAY_ID) AS Pays

from transactions
WHERE
DATE(DATE_SUB(created_at, INTERVAL 5 hour)) > current_date()-365

GROUP BY Project, Player, Date
```

Comment: Что такое "размер запроса" ? он возвращает те же результаты ?

Comment: *ему при этом нужно обработать в 20-30 раз меньше строк* Это с какой такой радости-то? Ему надо для КАЖДОЙ строки посчитать указанное выражение, и только потом сравнивать. Так что обработать ему по-любому надо ВСЕ строки. Типичный full table scan. Почитайте, что такое SARGable condition...

Comment: 34 гигабайта- не результат, а сколько памяти он сжирает вместе с деньгами

Comment: https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2023/06/bigquery-efficiency-tips?hl=ru
Тут описано , что как раз where  и ограничение даты должно сильно облегчать запрос, но этого не происходит

Answer (score 1):

Разница с тем что [в советах](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2023/06/bigquery-efficiency-tips?hl=ru) в том, что там колонка напрямую сравнивается с каким-то константным выражением (пусть выражение и использует сложную функцию от `CURRENT_DATE()`).

```
WHERE data_date between DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 14 day) ...
```

у вас же сложная функция применена к колонке, и потом сравнивается с каким-то выражением

```
DATE(DATE_SUB(created_at, INTERVAL 5 hour)) > current_date()-365
```

В их примере системе очень просто посчитать выражение и понять какие диапазоны `data_date` подходят, не проверяя каждого значения `data_date`. В этом и состоит экономия денег - быстро отсечь большинство партиций / кластеров, не смотря на конкретные значения (данные конечно должны быть PARTITIONED BY или CLUSTERED BY по этой колонке, или хотя бы по какой-нибудь коррелирующей с ней).

В вашем примере всё наоборот - какая-то сложная функция от `created_at`, как по ней оптимизатору понять какие диапазоны `created_at` подходят? Для этого оптимизатору надо было бы посчитать обратную функцию от вашей, что в общем случае невозможно, и он этим и не занимается кроме простейших случаев. Остается только проверять каждое значение, то есть full table scan.

Зато вы можете сделать это сами, записав условие в виде чего-то вроде

```
created_at > TIMESTAMP_ADD(TIMESTAMP(current_date() - 365), INTERVAL 5 HOUR)
```

(наверное я ошибся где-то в переписывании условия, но идея должна быть понятна)

Comment: спасибо , уже разобрался что таблица индексирвоана по другому полю dt  и если сделать 
DATE(dt) > current_date()-30
то запрос значительно  оптимизируется